# How to create a PACKAGE_VERSION struct in c#

Tags: c#, struct

I'm new to c# and I need a little help in creating struct in c# to represent this C++ example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/appmodel/ns-appmodel-package_version

```
typedef struct PACKAGE_VERSION {
  union {
    UINT64 Version;
    struct {
      USHORT Revision;
      USHORT Build;
      USHORT Minor;
      USHORT Major;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
  } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} PACKAGE_VERSION;
```

I will have a Version Class (System), like 1.0.0.0, which I need to convert into this Package_Version structure for use with PackageFullNameFromId function (appmodel.h).

I've read online that struct like this with a union are often unique to how you actually want to use it, and I can't find an examples for this, and I'm not even 100% sure what things to google for it.

Any help or points in the right direction would be welcome?

Answer (score 0):

I had tried ChatGPT but forgot to try GPT4, it came up with the answer where regular ChatGPT failed :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct PACKAGE_VERSION
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ulong Version;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ushort Revision;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public ushort Build;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public ushort Minor;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public ushort Major;
}
```